# Projection of closed set

Tags: general-topology

Set $A \subset R^2$, set B is projection of A on x-axis. Do you know a counterexample to the statement: if A is closed, then B is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the graph of $\tan(x)$ between two asymptotes.

Comment: Interesting example. Just to make sure that I got it right: any continuous line (like tan betwenn $\frac {-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac {\pi}{2}$) is closed because it contains all its limit points. Also, any point of the continuous line is limit point. right?

Comment: @John: True (though I'd say "curve" instead of "line")! Nice non-canonical counterexample, Asaf!

Comment: @Cameron: Thanks. I just happened to think about that one a few days ago (as a nice solution for this very problem). I actually thought about "The graph of any homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $\Bbb R$", but the principle is the same.

Comment: Thank you, Asaf! It's always funny when the example OP needs is quite obvious after being told about it.

Comment: I always contented myself with $\{xy=1\}$. That was lazy, +1.

Comment: @julien: Strange how when I thought about it a few days ago, it didn't pop right into my head... :-)

Comment: I think it is a bit like I would automatically take $\sin(1/x)$ to produce a connected non path-connected space.

Comment: @julien: We would? I recall some sort of comb space being the example...

Comment: Edited: I would...

Comment: @julien: I would eat a piece of wood if I had to carry out the $\log$!

Comment: I disagree with [@Git Gud](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10155/can-the-same-person-have-multiple-accounts): I am pretty sure you are the funniest person on MSE.

Comment: @julien: Hah! In the sixth grade I was the least funny kid in my class. I still have a great tendency to make tons of corny jokes (from a recent conference, they were discussing how come there is no Cantor Research Center, "Is there a Turing Research Center For Computational Sciences or something? I'm sure many people would love to have a [Turing degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree)!" - the table goes silent. And that was *after* the first bottle of wine!)

Answer (score 1):

Take $A = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 \hspace{2mm} | \hspace{2mm} xy = 1\}$ and $B$ being the projection of $A$ onto the $x$ - axis. Then $A$ is closed being the zero set of the polynomial $xy - 1$ but $B$ is not as it is $\Bbb{R} - \{0\}$.